# Highlight initial variable assignment in python with VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to use `tokenColor` in Visual Studio Code to highlight the initial binding of a variable in python. That is to say, the first time a variable name appears in its scope, I would like it to have a different color. This would usually be where the keyword "let" or "var" would be used in JavaScript. How would I go about adding this to VSCode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using a simple language grammar as it requires understanding the structure of the program itself (i.e. understanding what are initial bindings  vs re-assignments). This type of highlighting is called semantic highlighting.

As of VS Code 1.29, you can implement a custom version of semantic coloring using [decorators](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/master/decorator-sample). A proper semantic highlighting api is tracked by [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/585)